# Android Record Video With Code In Background

Tags: java, android, audio-recording

I was wondering what the best way to do this is. What I'm hoping to do is have a user push a button and automatically take a 10 second video, then save it to the SD card. I've seen how to do it through creating a new Intent, but the user then has to do the extra step of pushing record after selecting that they want to go to video. My goal is for them to push one button--one in my app that says "record", have it start recording for 10 seconds, then stop and save. In addition, I'd like to have some code executing in the background without being interrupted during said recording. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the camera with an Intent is simply opening the system camera app to take a picture/video. For more advanced usage, you can control the camera directly. Full details are in *[Controlling the Camera](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html)* (from [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

You should make a service for that.